# Download mp3s from url array to zip file

Tags: php, download, zip, mp3

I have an array of links to mp3 files. I need to have all of the mp3s downloaded from a server and then zipped.

This code below is not working:

Any suggestions?

```
$audio_flies = array('http://example.com/1.mp3','http://example.com/2.mp3');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($audio_files as $file) {
    echo "$file";
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

> **The archive is either in unknown format or damaged**

Comment: Where in this code are you downloading the files?! Are you sure that `addFile()` encapsulates the downloading process? (Which I highly doubt)

Comment: so far I am not downloading them. This is kind of what I need help with. Sorry my question was not as clear.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to download those files and store them locally on your server. Once that is done you will be able to zip them and make the zip file available for download.

The most basic way of achieving this is by using PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

*This code has not been thoroughly tested.*

```
// Fixed the name of the array
$audio_files = array('http://example.com/1.mp3', 'http://example.com/2.mp3');

// You need to change this to 
// a path where you want to store your 
// audio files (Absolute path is best)
$local_path = '/local/path/here/';
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Download the files
// Not an elegant way to 
// download files
foreach ($audio_files as $file) {
    // First let's get the file name
    // by parsing the URL
    // and trimming the '/'
    $file_name = ltrim(parse_url($file, PHP_URL_PATH), '\/');

    // Download the file
    $a_contents = file_get_contents($file);

    // Place the downloaded content
    // in the defined local path
    file_put_contents($local_path . $file_name, $a_contents);

    // Add the file to archive
    $zip->addFile($local_path . $file_name);
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

This **is a very bad way to achieve your task** for the following reasons (among many others):

1. There is no timeout for the download process
2. If a file fails to download it will halt the execution
3. It may take a very long time (depending on the size of the audio files) to serve the zip file
4. There is no proper error / exception handler
5. Many other reasons regarding structure that I'm not gonna go through here.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful information BassemDy. Do you have any suggestions to get many mp3s URL's into a zip? From URL's?

Comment: The database of mp3s will be changing so it needs to be dynamic, however, maybe I could run the script once a day and store the zip on a server and then link to download that zip?

Comment: Yes, you could use a unix tool like `wget` running via a cronjob to download and zip these files and store them in a local directory. Then you will be serving the zip file upon need from the disk instead of creating it each time upon request!

Answer (score -1):

try the following:  use parse_url to get the actual filename, use file_get_contents and file_put_contents to download and save the data locally...

```
$audio_flies = array('http://example.com/1.mp3','http://example.com/2.mp3');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($audio_files as $file) {
  echo "$file";
  $parsed = parse_url($file); 
  $localfile = "." . $parsed["path"];
  $mp3 = get_file_contents($file);
  file_file_contents($localfile, $mp3);
  $zip->addFile($localfile);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: I am getting a Fatal Error with this code:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_file_contents()

Comment: I'm voting this answer down because you use two functions that are undefined, and you fail to notice the misspell of the array name.